# Add existing java project to maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, svn, deployment

I have the following problem:

Using Eclipse, I created a maven Spring project running at localhost. My task is to create a deployment procedure for moving the local project to dev/production server.

The flow is the following: I commit the changes to the corporate SVN. I wrote a script, which downloads the latest revision to the dev server. I also have maven installed on the same server.

How do I tell maven to build this project (let's say the source is downloaded from the SVN to `/home/project1/latest/`), so I can rsync the compiled java class files to the tomcat root directory?

Comment: have u tried sourceDirectory in build tag `<sourceDirectory>/home/project1/latest/</sourceDirectory>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always the best practice to build the project in a common Build server(using continuous integration utility like Jenkins) and then distributing the same jar/war files to the required environment.
This will make sure that the tested code-base gets upgraded to higher environments.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'll discuss this with the management and we'll see what they would say.